# Why is justify-content center not working in form?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to make the form go to the center of the page but its just staying at the top of the page.

```css
body {margin: 0}

.form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<form class='form' method='POST' action='/users' id='register'>
  <h2>Register</h2>
  <label>Username</label>
  <input name='username' required>
  <label>Password</label>
  <input type='password' name='password' required>
  <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: 1. Form is not full height. 2. Better to put flex on its parent.

Comment: it works but there is nothing to center

Comment: I want to center the form and all its contents. Should I wrap it in a div and then center it?

Comment: Just add `height: 100vh` if you want to do it fast and easy.

Comment: Yeah that worked, thanks